# Ask an equation to solve the next location of an object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

[image]

It is a long time that I have not learnt physics. But now I really need an equation to solve a problem. I appreciate physicists give me a little hint. 
Here is a object on the desk without friction. There are two forces on it with opposite forces. There is no pivot.  So what kind of equation should I to calculate the next location of this object.

As a human being, I think it will end up like [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case of effect on a body due to couple forces.As there is no resultant external force,its com will not move.the body will have a circular motion with constant angular motion.This angular acceleration can also be calculated as follows:    Let the length of the stick be L and mass M.Moment of inertia is I=(ML^2)/12.Now torque due to couple force will be 2FL which equals I*a.where a is angular acceleration.Hence 2FL=Ia.from here a comes out to be a=24F/(ML).now if this stick makes an angle of  ø with horizontal,then we can apply equation for any time t as,ø=0.5at^2.

Comment: Thank you. I assume the two force are instant force and I have to add some friction so after a little while the rod will stop. So I want to know how this rod rotate? Could you so kind give me an equation?

Comment: Does that mean you are leaving both forces after applying once?

Comment: yes, The difficulty to me is there is no pivot.

Comment: If that's the difficulty,then there is no need to worry.The centre point will remain stationary as i said in my above answer.It will act like a pivot.

Comment: You're assuming the forces are equal in magnitude, which may be true, but it certainly doesn't look that way in the picture.

Comment: @JavierBadia, No, they are not equal.